# How to use date as filter

Tags: r, date, dataframe, matrix

My knowledge of R and scripting in general is almost not existent. So I hope you will be patient with this basic question.

```
library(lubridate)
date.depature <- c("2016.06.16", "2016.11.16", "2017.01.05", "2017.01.12", "2017.02.25")
airport.departure <- c("CDG", "QNY", "QXO", "CDG", "QNY")
airport.arrival <- c("SYD", "CDG", "QNY", "SYD", "QXO")
amount <- c("1", "3", "1", "10", "5")
date.depature <- as_date(date.depature)
df <- data.frame(date.depature, airport.departure, airport.arrival, amount)

xtabs(as.integer(amount) ~ airport.arrival + airport.departure, df)
```

With this code we get the sum of the amount as a matrix with the airports as row/column. Now I need just the results for

1. 2017
2. 2017.01
3. until 2017.01

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're already using `lubridate`, I'm going to show you an approach using [`dplyr`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org) (part of the `tidyverse` alongside lubridate).

The solutions all apply. `filter` alongside `month`, `year` and `as_date` functions from `lubridate` to create conditions to filter your data, then use the [pipe `%>%`](https://magrittr.tidyverse.org) to pass that long to `xtabs`

```r
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
library(lubridate)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'lubridate'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     date

date.depature <- c("2016.06.16", "2016.11.16", "2017.01.05", "2017.01.12", "2017.02.25")
airport.departure <- c("CDG", "QNY", "QXO", "CDG", "QNY")
airport.arrival <- c("SYD", "CDG", "QNY", "SYD", "QXO")
amount <- c("1", "3", "1", "10", "5")
date.depature <- as_date(date.depature)
df <- data.frame(date.depature, airport.departure, airport.arrival, amount)

# For 2017
df %>% 
  filter(year(date.depature) == 2017) %>% 
  xtabs(as.integer(amount) ~ airport.arrival + airport.departure, .)
#>                airport.departure
#> airport.arrival CDG QNY QXO
#>             CDG   0   0   0
#>             QNY   0   0   1
#>             QXO   0   4   0
#>             SYD   2   0   0

# 2017.01
df %>% 
  filter(year(date.depature) == 2017, month(date.depature) == 1) %>% 
  xtabs(as.integer(amount) ~ airport.arrival + airport.departure, .)
#>                airport.departure
#> airport.arrival CDG QNY QXO
#>             CDG   0   0   0
#>             QNY   0   0   1
#>             QXO   0   0   0
#>             SYD   2   0   0

# until 2017.01
df %>% 
  filter(date.depature <= as_date("2017.01.01")) %>% 
  xtabs(as.integer(amount) ~ airport.arrival + airport.departure, .)
#>                airport.departure
#> airport.arrival CDG QNY QXO
#>             CDG   0   3   0
#>             QNY   0   0   0
#>             QXO   0   0   0
#>             SYD   1   0   0
```

<sup>Created on 2018-11-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you coerce `amount` to class `"integer"` when you create `df`? Just get rid of the double quotes in

```
amount <- c("1", "3", "1", "10", "5")
```

or

```
amount <- as.integer(c("1", "3", "1", "10", "5"))
```

This is because `as.integer(df$amount)` **does not** return

```
c(1, 3, 1, 10, 5)
```

When you create the dataframe `df` that vector is coerced to class `"factor"` and what you now have is

```
as.integer(df$amount)
#[1] 1 3 1 2 4
```

The right way would be

```
as.integer(as.character(df$amount))
#[1]  1  3  1 10  5
```

Or more simply:

```
date.depature <- c("2016.06.16", "2016.11.16", "2017.01.05", "2017.01.12", "2017.02.25")
airport.departure <- c("CDG", "QNY", "QXO", "CDG", "QNY")
airport.arrival <- c("SYD", "CDG", "QNY", "SYD", "QXO")
amount <- c(1, 3, 1, 10, 5)
date.depature <- as_date(date.depature)
df <- data.frame(date.depature, airport.departure, airport.arrival, amount)
```

**Now the question.**

This is basically a subsetting problem.
Subset the data extracting the years and months you want then run the same `xtabs` command.

```
df1 <- df[year(df$date.depature) == 2017, ]
df2 <- df1[month(df1$date.depature) == 1, ]
df3 <- cbind(df[year(df$date.depature) < 2017, ], df2)
```

Now `xtabs`, with the sub-dataframes above.

```
xtabs(amount ~ airport.arrival + airport.departure, df1)
xtabs(amount ~ airport.arrival + airport.departure, df2)
xtabs(amount ~ airport.arrival + airport.departure, df3)
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for explaining the integer-problem to me. I was not aware of that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to subset date.departure in your xtabs call. For year == 2017:

```
xtabs(as.integer(amount) ~ airport.arrival + airport.departure, df[year(df$date.depature)==2017,])
```

For year==2017 and month==1:

```
xtabs(as.integer(amount) ~ airport.arrival + airport.departure, df[year(df$date.depature)==2017 & month(df$date.departure)==1,])
```

And for anything before Jan 2017:

```
xtabs(as.integer(amount) ~ airport.arrival + airport.departure, df[df$date.depature<as_date("2017-01-01"),])
```